# "He broke out in a grin"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Her face broke out in a grin as she nodded, her ponytail swinging. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=lGD1pS_UhzkC&pg=PT22&lpg=PT22&dq=%22broke%20out%20in%20a%20grin%22&source=bl&ots=5wNmvBNIo6&sig=AvsdqP5dRxdGZh76jenMAN8V5hk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7ycGgtpvfAhUvUt8KHd_lCk4Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22broke%20out%20in%20a%20grin%22&f=false))
>
> Lee broke out in a grin and went on. ([source](http://www.cantonrep.com/article/20160218/SPORTS/302189992/0/%E2%80%9D//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PXCWJQ%E2%80%9D))
>
> Wondering what the jocularity was about, Matsuzaka finally noticed the bubble as it fell off his hat and he broke out in a grin. ([source](http://archive.boston.com/sports/baseball/redsox/articles/2007/11/04/well_earned_recognition/))

I have seen "break out in a grin" in several places. The closest entry in dictionaries is

> (of a person or a part of their body) be suddenly affected by an unpleasant sensation or condition.
>   *"something had caused him to break out in a rash"*

My understanding is "He broke out in a grin" means something like "His face broke into a grin". Is that correct? Besides "grin", what are some other words that can be used in this expression?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is explained by this definition of the phrasal verb 'break into' from [M-WD](http://break%20into%201%20:%20to%20begin%20with%20or%20as%20if%20with%20a%20sudden%20throwing%20off%20of%20restraint%20broke%20into%20tears%20face%20breaking%20into%20a%20smile%20the%20horse%20breaks%20into%20a%20gallop).

> **break into**
>
> 1 : to begin with or as if with a sudden throwing off of restraint
>
> Examples. *broke into tears; face breaking into a smile; the horse breaks into a gallop*

'Break out in' is just an alternative way of saying 'break into'.